# I need to reduce scatter chart plot size to allow -90 labels and add Errors Bars in VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2016

I created an Excel 2016 VBA scatter chart (separate worksheet w/o legends) and labeled the points with VBA.  Source labels are A1:A3 (Events (35-chars) / Date / Y-points) and Data is A2:C17.  My labels (orientation -90) overwrite the Y-points and bunch up because the Y-axis plot area takes up the entire worksheet.  I have tried different Y-axis values but the plot area expands to fill the worksheet. I have also tried to change the plot size with VBA.  I need the labels above the actual chart plot.

The secondary issue is I cannot plot a Date & Time, just a Date and have a problem creating Error Bars with xlMinusValues 100% and SeriesCollection(1).

I have been doing this in separate modules for ease of use, but will be combining or using a Call.  I find I cannot build a chart with more than 16 data records, so I will be working on a looping routine if more records are present.

***TIMELINE MODULE***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Timeline()

    Dim sCount As Long
    Dim labelrotation As Long
    Dim TimelineChart As Chart
    Dim LastCell As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngAddr As String
    Dim ChartRange As String

    With ActiveSheet
        Range("C1").End(xlDown).Activate
        Set rng = ActiveCell
        rngAddr = rng.Address(0, 0)
    End With

    Let ChartRange = "B2:" & rngAddr

    Set TimelineChart = Charts.Add
    TimelineChart.Name = "TimelineChart"
    With TimelineChart
        .SetSourceData Sheets("TimelineData").Range(ChartRange)
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .Legend.LegendEntries(1).Delete
        TimelineChart.HasAxis(xlSecondary) = False
    End With

End Sub
```

***LABEL MODULE***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Labels()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim Events As Range
    Dim EventCounter As Integer
    Dim s As Series

    Sheets("TimelineData").Select
    Set Events = Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    Set s = Chart1.SeriesCollection(1)

    s.HasDataLabels = True

    For Each r In Events

        EventCounter = EventCounter + 1
        s.Points(EventCounter).DataLabel.Text = r.Value
        s.Points(EventCounter).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
        s.Points(EventCounter).DataLabel.Orientation = 45
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: (1) No screenshots? I can't envision your issue. (2) `Charts.Add`? You're not talking about the chart filling a worksheet, but it's a chart sheet (a totally different animal). (3) Dates and times? Error bars? I don't see them.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to withdraw the question.  The scatter plot was on a chart sheet versus in the same worksheet as the table from which data is used.  Lots of hours spent with a conclusion I should use a bar chart, same worksheet, modified.

Thanks to all that looked and considered a response.